# 2005 Ford Windstar constantly blows windshield wiper fuse

Tags: ford, windstar

I'm curious what options there are for non-mechanics in diagnosing and correcting an issue where fuses for the Windshield Wipers on my 2005 Ford Windstar Mini-Van keep blowing? Upon placing the new fuse in the slot there is a snap and the fuse is blown.

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of a fuse blowing is always because too high a current is passing through it, so you need to find out why.

Realistically, options are:

- A short circuit in the wiring to the wiper motor - which you can diagnose with a multimeter
- A failure in the wiper motor itself - best tested (by a non-mechanic) by replacing with a know good one

Comment: Where they are exposed to a lot of water, the spindles on wiper systems can become seized/seizing causing a high current and blowing the fuse. Before putting your hands anywhere near the wiper linkage to check for stiffness, DISCONNECT THE WIPER MOTOR PLUG so that it cannot operate. If the you do not do so and the motor operates, serious personel injury will result.